# CSS grid auto width in IE and MS Edge not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, css-grid

Have an IE and Edge specific problem. Fooling around with "CSS grid layout" and `auto` width seems not to work in IE 10/11 or even in newest version of Edge. (Works fine in Chrome and FireFox.)

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/lamemule/pen/JyGvGp)

```css
.test {
  width 100%;
}

.test #contain {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 50px 10px auto;
  -ms-grid-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.test .sec1 {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.test .sec2 {
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div id="contain">
    <div class="sec1">1</div>
    <div class="sec2">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So is the error on my part or did Microsoft make lame stuff again?

Besides I thought that Edge should have a full implementation of the latest CSS grid but I guess not since I still need to use `-ms`.

Comment: IE10/11 uses older syntax as does Edge until version 16. http://caniuse.com/#search=grid As always Microsoft browsers are a mess.

Comment: @Rob Grid works in IE10.

Comment: If you're only gonna use the second column of your grid (sec2 starts in column 3 & sec 1 only occupies 1 column), I would advise into using the grid-gutters. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-gap. I've recently also started using Grid and for modern browsers it's a joy. For anything Microsoft related I find it a pain.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Yep. Mis-remembered.

Comment: @Rob Your comment about old syntax is not relevant because OP successfully used it. He added manual cell positioning for IE/Edge and faked `grid-gap` using extra column.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov It doesn't make it any less true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue that IE/Edge CSS Grid layout works according to old [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/#grid-columns-and-rows-properties) where

> `auto` is equivalent to `minmax(min-content, max-content)`.

And according to new [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#track-sizing)

> `auto`
>   As a maximum, identical to [`max-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-grid-template-columns-max-content). As a minimum, represents the largest minimum size (as specified by [`min-width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-width)/[`min-height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-min-height)) of the grid items occupying the [`grid track`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-track).

---

In this example you don't need `auto` value, you need `1fr` to occupy all remaining width. By the way some styles are redundant in you code. Demo:

```css
.test {
  width 100%;
}

.test #contain {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 50px 10px 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.test .sec1 {
  /* this is default value for IE/Edge, grid items always stack in first cell for IE/Edge */
  -ms-grid-row: 1;  /* redundant */
  -ms-grid-column: 1;  /* redundant */
  background-color: red;
}

.test .sec2 {
  /* this is default value for IE/Edge, grid items always stack in first cell for IE/Edge */
  -ms-grid-row: 1; /* redundant */
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  /* all this value will be used by default due to auto-placement of grid items (which is not working in IE/Edge) */
  grid-column-start: 2; /* redundant */
  grid-column-end: 3; /* redundant */
  grid-row-start: 1; /* redundant */
  grid-row-end: 2; /* redundant */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div id="contain">
    <div class="sec1">1</div>
    <div class="sec2">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`auto` in IE != `auto` in modern browsers.**

`auto` in IE strictly equals `minmax(min-content, max-content)`.

In modern browsers `auto` still essentially acts like `minmax(min-content, max-content)` except it is able to *exceed* the size of the `max-content` value when stretched by the `align-content` and `justify-content` properties. **IE doesn't allow that.** `auto` in IE cannot exceed the size of the `max-content` value.

Another difference is that `auto` in IE cannot be used inside a `minmax()` function. This is because `auto` = `minmax(min-content, max-content)` in IE and `minmax()` functions are not allowed to be nested inside one another.

Modern browsers allow `auto` to be used inside `minmax()` because `auto` has different functionalities depending on if it is used as a min value, a max value or used on it's own.

> **'auto'**
>
> As a maximum, identical to max-content. As a minimum, represents the largest minimum size (as specified by min-width/min-height) of the grid items occupying the grid track.
>
> **Note:** auto track sizes (and only auto track sizes) can be stretched by the align-content and justify-content properties.
>
> source: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#valdef-grid-template-columns-auto

**To take up the remaining space in a grid, use `1fr` instead.**

See this series of articles on how to effectively work with the IE implementation of CSS Grid:
https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-debunking-common-ie-grid-misconceptions/